# PHP Carbon does not calculate the time difference

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, php-carbon

I need to get the time difference.But carbon does not calculate.

```
date1  2022-03-30 00:00:00   
date2  2022-03-30 21:00:00  

$interval = $date1->diffInSeconds($date2);            -> OUTPUT: 0
$interval2 = $date1->diffAsCarbonInterval($date2);    -> OUTPUT:
```

Comment: did you try $interval = $date2->diffInSeconds($date1);

Comment: @AqibJaved Yes, I also tried changing places

Comment: dis you get same output ?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand what the problem is. Maybe its just calculating the day difference.

Comment: $date1 and $date 2 are carbon instance right?

Comment: @Zelensky please try after parsing date into carbon instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse all the data with Carbon to convert it to Carbon instance, then you can get the difference

```
 $diffInSeconds = Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-03-30 00:00:00')->diffInSeconds(Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-03-30 21:00:00'));
```